# Calculate the third point, given two points of an equilateral triangle?

Tags: python, opencv

i wish to know apart from distance formula, is there any other way to calculate the third point of an equilateral triangle ?. I was going through the below snippet which does similarity transform between two points. I dont understand how they are calculating the third point.

```
def similarityTransform(inPoints, outPoints):
  s60 = math.sin(60*math.pi/180)
  c60 = math.cos(60*math.pi/180)

  inPts = np.copy(inPoints).tolist()
  outPts = np.copy(outPoints).tolist()

  # The third point is calculated so that the three points make an equilateral triangle
  xin = c60*(inPts[0][0] - inPts[1][0]) - s60*(inPts[0][1] - inPts[1][1]) + inPts[1][0]
  yin = s60*(inPts[0][0] - inPts[1][0]) + c60*(inPts[0][1] - inPts[1][1]) + inPts[1][1]

  inPts.append([np.int(xin), np.int(yin)])

  xout = c60*(outPts[0][0] - outPts[1][0]) - s60*(outPts[0][1] - outPts[1][1]) + outPts[1][0]
  yout = s60*(outPts[0][0] - outPts[1][0]) + c60*(outPts[0][1] - outPts[1][1]) + outPts[1][1]

  outPts.append([np.int(xout), np.int(yout)])

  # Now we can use estimateRigidTransform for calculating the similarity transform.
  tform = cv2.estimateAffinePartial2D(np.array([inPts]), np.array([outPts]))
  return tform[0]
```

Why we need to calculate thrid point because In opencv, `estimateAffinePartial2D` need three points to calculate similarity matrix. And we have only two points.

Comment: You mean the third point_s_, right?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes

Comment: Looks like they're taking the sine and cosine and multiplying to find the distance, then rotating appropriately.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, But then i wish to know what’s the logic behind taking cosine and sine and then rotating to calculate third point.

Comment: There are many answered questions on SO about implementing various algorithms for this, but understanding the math behind it is, well, math, not programming. Geometry and/or trigonometry, specifically, depending on the algorithm.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Okay I agree. Thank you